# PDF prints don't look the same as the on the computer

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, print-design

I've created some images in Illustrator (simple portraits to be exact). I have been using the "Save As" option to save PDF Versions to email to my boss for the past few weeks.

Here is my problem: Now that I have begun printing, the prints have glitches all over them. Some of the shapes and paths are not filled all the way in and have white spaces, and in some spots I can see the bottom layers coming through the top layers.

For example, the white of the eyes may show up on the eye-lid, even though the eye-lid is on TOP. I'm not understanding why the PDF files look so great on the computer screen, but my prints look so screwed-up.

Comment: Welcome. It is someone impossible to assist without seeing how the file is constructed.

Comment: If PDFs look ok, then what happens when you print those, rather than direct from Illustrator? It's almost certainly an issue with your printer driver (and you haven't said which printer you're using or what driver). However, sorting out printer drivers is almost certainly off-topic here, and the question might be migrated.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Some PDF viewing software interprets things differently to others - I'd suggest printing from Illustrator directly if you haven't already.

Comment: can you post examples? Are you sure there is no issues with your designs? What are your print settings?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to save the PDF without keeping the layers, and uncheck "Keep illustrator compatibility"? These settings are found when you go into "Save as...".

If this doesn't work - save it directly as an image (jpeg with high quality). Of course you will loose the vector advantages - but the layers won't be visible in print.